# US to Canada by car with an enhanced driver's license, no passport?

Tags: passports, canada, borders

I recall enhanced drivers licenses (EDL) being advertised as a way to travel between north american countries without a passport. It is clear that a US citizen can get back into the US with only an EDL: [US CBP - What is an Enhanced Driver's License (EDL)?](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1269?language=en_US). However, Canada's entry requirements are less clear. On [Travel and identification documents for entering Canada](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html#s3), it says

> What [travel documents] you need will depend on where you are from, how you are travelling, and what documents you are travelling with. Consult [entry requirements by country](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/entry-requirements-country.html#us-citizens).

However, all this says for US citizens is

> U.S. citizens must [carry proper identification](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html#s3) such as a valid U.S. passport.

This links back to the "Travel and identification documents for entering Canada" page. It doesn't clarify what counts as proper identification. Nothing mentions EDLs, and the circular reference doesn't help clear things up. Given all this I'm assuming that an EDL doesn't count, but I'm not confident that's correct.

So, is it possible to enter Canada from the US with an enhanced driver's license, but no passport?

---

For slightly more context, this is for a friend who wants to travel to Canada in a week or so. They currently have an enhanced non-driver ID, but no passport. However, I am interested in the more general question above that will be more helpful to future readers.

Comment: Have you asked Canada Immigration?

Comment: You could always get a passport card...

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I have not

Comment: @littleadv Passports and passport cards both have a very long processing time. The planned travel is unimportant enough that it is not worth trying to expedite any processes.

Comment: [The WA DoL indicates that it's allowed](https://www.dol.wa.gov/driverslicense/edlfaq.html) and anecdotally I've crossed the border via ferry with just an EDL, but hopefully someone can find something from the Canadian government

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its kind of buried on the Canadian government website but the official [list of acceptable documents](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/trans/guide-eng.html?wbdisable=true) is:

> U.S. Citizens/Nationals
> Although exempt from document entry
> requirements, U.S. citizens must satisfy a CBSA officer of their
> status and identity. Documents that can be used for proof of U.S.
> citizenship are:
>
> - U.S. Passport
> - U.S. Passport Card (for land and marine travel only)
> - NEXUS card (see Part 6 for more information)
> - Enhanced Driver's License
>   (for land and marine travel only)

And as [per Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_driver%27s_license):

> EDLs are available to U.S. citizens who reside in the states of Michigan, Minnesota, New York, Vermont, and Washington.

So your friend is good to go.

Comment: Actually Canada still seems to have even less stringent document requirements than that list for Americans entering Canada; [a valid photo ID and some proof of citizenship](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/ivc-rnc-eng.html) (say, a regular DL and a birth certificate) is sufficient. The advantage of the particular documents in your list is that they should also allow a hassle-free return to the US.

Comment: But not Alaska, Idaho, Montana, North Dakota, Wisconsin, New Hampshire, or Maine?  (Or I guess Ohio or Pennsylvania, though they don't share a *land* border).  I wonder why not?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Driver licensing is the responsibility of the state (or province in Canada). If the state or province does not see enough benefits of issuing EDLs (which costs money in training, IT updates, etc. auditing/compliance, security features), they do not have to participate in the enhanced licence program.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Notably, in Canada, Quebec and Ontario have ended its EDL program a few years ago and B.C. and Manitoba are phasing out EDLs by around 2025 (so no Canadian province will be issuing new EDLs from next year). EDLs were supposed to be a cheap alternative to passport, but NEXUS was created in 2009  and biometric Canadian passport with 10-year validity (instead of five before) became available in 2013. More persons now have a passport and do not see the need to have an EDL.

Answer (score 2):

An [Enhanced Driver's License](https://www.dhs.gov/enhanced-drivers-licenses-what-are-they) is the functional equivalent of a [Passport Card](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/need-passport/card.html) as far as Canada is concerned.

The EDL is a bit cheaper than a plain driver's license + Federal Passport Card, because much of the identity checking parallels what the state is doing *anyway* to grant you an ID or driver's license (to comply with the Federal RealID rules).  Each state needs to work with DHS to be eligible to issue Enhanced DL/ID, and many states do not bother.

Comment: An EDL is not currently considered valid travel document to travel into Mexico. Only passport or passport card are officially recognised as acceptable.

Comment: Re: "much of the identity checking parallels what the state is doing *anyway* to grant you an ID or driver's license (to comply with the Federal RealID rules)": That depends on the state. In Washington state, ordinary driver's licenses and ID cards do *not* comply with REAL ID; only enhanced ones do.

Comment: @midalvo ok, thanks. That explains why Cali, NM etc. don't offer it.

Comment: @ruakh that is crazy, that means most of their citizens will have trouble flying in  October 30 2296 when Starfleet finally puts their foot down and says "no more darn RealID extensions".

Comment: I’d be extremely surprised if RealID actually starts being enforced in this decade…

Comment: @ruakh, Harper-ReinstateMonica: worse, it means that foreigners living in Washington will be unable to use their driver's licenses to fly, because they cannot get enhanced driver's licenses, so they'll have to use a green card, if they have one, or foreign passport.

Comment: @phoog: I think that non-citizens would anyway have to have some acceptable form of ID, no? Are non-citizens allowed to live in the U.S. without a green card or visa? (Oh, though I guess they might have an *expired* ID. Still, I'd expect that to be far less common than American citizens with no passport.)

Comment: @ruakh most noncitizens are required to have a valid green card or passport.  A valid visa is not necessary (nor is it helpful with the TSA).  Rather, other documents can show that they have valid status, but these are also unhelpful with the TSA.  Furthermore, some noncitizens can be admitted as nonimmigrants beyond the validity of their passport.  If they live in Washington, they'll have trouble flying while renewing their passport or applying for a visa to visit another country (for which they might need to travel somewhere that is impractical except by air).

Comment: A non-citizen on an extended visit might need to submit the passport for a visa, and not have it in their possession. They could have their I-94 form as proof of legal presence, but can't use it to fly domestically. In most states they could get a Real ID driver license so they can fly if/when Real ID is enforced, but not in the State of Washington